# Cannot convert my String to Date

Tags: java, string, date, date-format, simpledateformat

i was searching how to convert a string to a date, so i've found some examples on stacko. . So i used SimpleDateFormat and tried to parse but my compiler (Gradle from AndroidStudio) send me this error : Unhandled exception : java.text.ParseException.
There is my code :

```
public static int compareDate(String sdate1, String sdate2) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", Locale.FRANCE);
    Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(sdate1); // there is the error
[...]

}
```

Why is there an error? Someone can explain that to me?
I'm a beginner in java and i'm sorry for my bad english, and i hope someone can help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us how does your string look like?

Comment: It's an issue with your locale

Comment: I enter in my function a String with the format "2013/07/01"

Comment: it still does not work. Even if I change local

Comment: try deleting locale argument

Comment: Darijan i will not delete my France locale argument. :D

Answer (score 7):

The `parse` method throws a `ParseException`. You need to insert a `catch` block or your method should throw `ParseException` in order to get rid of the error:

```
public static int compareDate(String sdate1, String sdate2) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", Locale.FRANCE);
    try {
        Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(sdate1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {              // Insert this block.
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

**OR**

```
public static int compareDate(String sdate1, String sdate2) throws ParseException{
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", Locale.FRANCE);
    Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(sdate1); 
}
```

Comment: That works :) . So it was just cause i don't used a try/catch bloc.

Comment: @bengous That works?? then accept it as answer, also give an upvote if it was hwlpful

Comment: And make sure you understand what you are doing: if a method CAN throw an Exception that does not extends RuntimeException, you HAVE TO handle it by catching it or declaring your method can throw that exception.

Comment: i cannot Upvote already :) . And @Pablo Lozano, i don't understand why i have to this on my code, so if you can explain me why i have to use a try/catch, i will be happy

Comment: Read this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html